# Match neither regex

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I have a Bash script which installs a customized JBoss. The name of the JBoss instance is checked against a regular expression to make sure that the name is valid:

```
if [[ ! $1 =~ $instanceNameRegex ]]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

We now have a requirement for a second valid regex. ie the name must match either `$instanceNameRegex` or `$secondInstanceNameRegex`.

How do I achieve this in the `if` test? I'm looking for this, but I can't get it to work:

```
if [[ [ ! $1 =~ $instanceNameRegex ] -a [ ! $1 =~ $secondInstanceNameRegex ] ]]; then
```

ie if the parameter doesn't match the first regex AND it doesn't match the second, then exit.

Comment: Since when has `[` been an argument to `[[`?

Comment: That's why I'm asking on here: I'm a Java programmer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
if [[ ! $1 =~ $instanceNameRegex && ! $1 =~ $secondInstanceNameRegex ]]; then
```

I would use instead:

```
if [[ ! ( $1 =~ $instanceNameRegex || $1 =~ $secondInstanceNameRegex ) ]]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
if [[ ! $1 =~ "${instanceNameRegex}|${secondInstanceNameRegex}" ]]; then
```